# trigonometric identity domain restrictions for tan * cos

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having some difficulty in evaluating the domain restriction on this true/false problem:

$$\tan(a) \cos(a) = \sin(a)\text{ for any }a \neq (2k + 1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I understand that the domain restriction of the $\tan$ function is all real numbers except $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer, and $\cos$ is all real numbers, but I'm unsure how to apply that information and test whether this is true or not. What is a good method for determining the proper domain for this problem and others like it?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor the $\pi$ out of the domain restriction for tangent that you listed, $\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, and rearrange. You'll see it matches the given restriction on $a$.

---

Recall that $\tan(x)$ can be represented as the quotient of $\frac{sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, meaning that tangent is undefined where $\cos(x) =0$. Your restriction ought to match the $x$ values where this occurs.

If you simplify the LHS, you'll see that it matches the RHS.